# Algorithms for seat arrangement

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Given is an undirected and connected graph. The vertices are persons and the edges between them model their relation. Iff X and Y have an edge (X, Y) the know each other directly. Because the graph is connected each person knows each other at least indirectly. If X knows Z indirectly there must be a person Y so that X knows Y and Y knows Z, what I mean is that every person can know every other person through at most one other person.

Now the task is to seat the people on tables so that on every table every person knows exactly two persons directly. Persons knowing each other directly should sit on opposing sites of the table and persons knowing each other indirectly should sit on the same site.

The question is now how many tables are needed.
I know some graph algorithms like mst, maximum flow, bfs, dfs, dijkstra and so on, but I couldn't come up with an algorithm that solves this problem so please help me.

Comment: "I mean is that every person can know every other person through at most one other person". For example  the graph A-B-C-D is connected. Does A know D "indirectly"? Are you claiming that in your graph all pairs of vertices have a path of length at most 2?

Comment: Also "on every table every person knows exactly two persons directly. Persons knowing each other should sit on opposing sites": If you have a simple triangle graph (i.e. 3 vertices all connected to each other), then there is no seating arrangement that satisfies both above conditions. Should you output "infeasible"?

Comment: @megas Yes, every path has the maximum length 2 (except for cycles). Actually I have given some concrete graph on which the problem should be solved but I was looking for a more general method. There are cases where there isn't a solution for sure. In this case there should be a way for determining it. The problem looks for me like a kind of matching but I can't figure out how to solve it. If it helps I could also show the concrete graph instance. So what I want to do is to reduce this problem to an already known one as one usually does :)